# Expose duplicate UUID to kvm guest

Tags: virtualization, uuid, qemu, kvm, libvirt

I'd like to run several VMs/domains at once that expose the same SMBIOS system UUID to the guest. I need to test several versions of software that uses SMBIOS UUID value to generate unique ID. For some reason libvirt demands that domain's top-level UUID is the same as UUID exposed to VM via SMBIOS. (as per [libvirt domain xml format](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsSysinfo) documentation)

> If this entry is provided alongside a top-level uuid element, then the
>   two values must match.

Therefore I cannot run two identical domains (from guest's perspective) in single libvirt instance.

Is there a way around this limitation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way around this. Having matching UUIDs visible from host and guest is one of the guarantees that libvirt provides to applications, allowing things like system monitoring agents to correlate guests OS with host OS they are running on.